# How can I initialize and operate Bootstrap Collapse without an ID?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

For some reason I want to use collapse without an ID. I found an old answer on stackoverflow and it seems it doesn't work in Bootstrap 5.

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: c.nextElementSibling.collapse is not a
> function

I believe the problem is `collapse('toggle')`. What should I do? I'm not using jQuery.

```js
let c = document.querySelector('.c');

c.addEventListener('click', () => {
  collapser.nextElementSibling.collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a class="nav-link c" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Has Sub</a>

<div class="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
  content...
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collapsing via Javascript in BootStrap 5 works slightly different compared to previous versions. In Bootstrap 5 you need to create a collapse instance with the constructor. For example:

```js
const c = document.querySelector('.c');
const collapse = c.nextElementSibling;

const myCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(collapse, {
  toggle: false
});

c.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myCollapse.toggle();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a class="nav-link c" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Has Sub</a>

<div class="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
  content...
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: But if I have more than one (.c) and want to change to querySelectorAll('.c'), this doesn't work, can you give me advice?